# xubuntu's desktop behaves abnormally

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, desktop-environments

My xubuntu used to work well but today it doesn't seem good:
[image]

As you can see, only a rectangle part is available now, the rest space is grey and right clicking the grey part doesn't seem to work...

I've tried cleaned my sessions and restart but it still won't work.

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Thank you!

---

EDIT 1:

[xrandr -q output](http://pastebin.com/aVSmqxWF)

[.xsession-errors](http://pastebin.com/NMGeqSkR)

Comment: Please add the contents of `~/.xsession-errors` and the output `xrandr -q` to your post.

Comment: @drc Please see my edits. FYI, there are some warnings in .xsession-errors and I've deleted them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have a desktop the size of your smaller monitor on your larger one.

Try running `xfce4-display-settings -m`, that should open a dialog like the one in this screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of xfce4-display-settings]

There, select **Extend to the right** (or left, if that's what it offers) instead of *Mirror displays*.

**Update**: If *Extend to the right* already is selected, try toggling it. Select **Mirror Displays**, which will display the some content on both your monitors, then call the dialog again and select **Extend to the right**.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem because I have selected "Extend to the right" and the snapshot I gave is what it looks on my right screen.

Comment: Have you tried toggling the settings?

Comment: @drc,but the top panel already extends the full width of the screen in the image.

Comment: @drc How to toggle the settings then? I think something is wrong with the xubuntu desktop on a second monitor. Everything is OK on my 1366*768 laptop screen, the problem only exists on my 1920*1080 monitor.

Comment: @drc are there any other log files that I can explore?

Comment: I suppose you could look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, might be something there. As for the toggling, see update.